# Plotting a vector amplitude in polar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've looked over many different threads and I can't seem to find a suitable option for my problem. I have a vector function in 2D, for which I want to plot the amplitude. So naturally, I defined a function, which looks quite ugly, but the point is, it's a function of r and theta. I'd like to color plot the amplitude and I must confess, I'm feeling a bit lost. I need to have a defined function value in every point in my 2D space and I'm not sure how to handle this. The code looks something like this;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#==============================================================================
# DEFINING PARAMETERS AND FUNCTIONS 
#==============================================================================

kb = 1.38e-23 #Boltzman [m²kg/(K*s²)]
e0 = 8.854e-12 #Vacuum permittivity, epsilon0 [F/m]
P = 1e-14 #Value of the static dipole moment
dpr = 0.1 #Dipole ratio, p/P, p = dpr*P
pi = np.pi
T = 300 #Temperature in Kelvins [K]

gamma = P*P*dpr/(4*pi*e0*T*kb)

#Average force in 2D space:

def F(r,theta):
    return [-1*kb*T/(2*pi + 0.5*(np.sin(theta)*gamma/(r**3))**2)*3*gamma**2*(np.sin(theta))**2/(r**7), kb*T/(2*pi + 0.5*(np.sin(theta)*gamma/(r**3))**2)*0.5*gamma**2 * np.sin(2*theta)/(r**7)]

#Amplitude of the vector:

def amp_2d(v):
    return np.sqrt(v[0]**2+v[1]**2)

#==============================================================================
# Plotting  
#==============================================================================

n = 150 #Number of points

r = np.linspace(0,1,n)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi,n)
```

My idea was to create some sort of list of tuples so I'd have 150*150 tuples with the form (r,theta,amp_2d(F(r,theta))), and that's pretty much where it stops.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this link https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d_radial.html.

You need to use meshgrid for 3d plot. You can do something like :

```
r = np.linspace(0.00001, 1, 100)
p = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
R, P = np.meshgrid(r, p)

Z = amp_2d([F(R,P)])

X, Y = R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P)

#Set the Z limits here
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)
plt.show()
```